# Need to select 'naam' from table 'gebruikers'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Need some help with this, only way i know to do this is using JOIN, but my query doesnt work?

Oh yeah  I know i should use PDO and mysqli instead but this is just for a personal project.

```
<?php
    //query voor tabel projecturen
   $samenvoegen = mysql_query("SELECT gebruikersid.projecturen gebruikersnaam.gebruikers FROM `projecturen` WHERE projectid= '$projecturenid' LEFT JOIN `gebruikers` ON gebruikersid.projecturen=gebruikersnaam.gebruikers ") 
   or die( mysql_error() );
   //toon wanneer er geen uren in de database staan
   if ( mysql_num_rows( $samenvoegen ) == 0 ) 
      echo '<h3 class="error">Er zijn nog geen uren ingevult voor dit project</h3>';
   else {
      while($svgebruiker = mysql_fetch_object( $samenvoegen ) ) {
   ?>
```

I'm new to PHP and SQL so don't be to harsh ;)

### SOLUTION! thanks for the help people

```
 <?php

                                //query voor tabel projecturen
                                $urenoverzicht = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `projecturen` INNER JOIN `gebruikers` ON gebruikers.id = projecturen.gebruikerid AND projectid='$projecturenid'") or die(mysql_error());


                                //toon wanneer er geen uren in de database staan
                                if (mysql_num_rows($urenoverzicht)==0) 
                                    echo '<h3 class="error">Er zijn nog geen uren ingevult voor dit project</h3>';
                                else 
                                {
                                    while($urenov = mysql_fetch_object($urenoverzicht))
                                {


                   ?>
```

Comment: The `WHERE` clause should be placed after the `JOIN` statements.

Comment: Even if it is for a personal project, use PDO or mySQLi. You need to develop the muscle memory to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wietze314 is correct in placing the WHERE clause after the JOIN statements, but the query is also missing a comma to separate the fields, plus it should be tablename.fieldname whereas you seem to be using fieldname.tablename?

So if your table names are `projecturen` and `gebruikers`, then it should be something like:

```
SELECT `projecturen`.datum
, `projecturen`.uren
, `gebruikers`.naam
FROM  `gebruikers`
LEFT JOIN `projecturen` ON `gebruikers`.id=`projecturen`.gebruikersid
WHERE `projecturen`.projectid= '$projecturenid'
```

Comment: Thanks, but right now its getting all the rows in the table "projecturen". I want to display: the 'datum' from table 'projecturen', 'uren' from the table 'projecturen', name from the table 'gebruikers'. Right now im showing the 'datum' and the 'uren' which are being get by the 'projectid'. Everytime ill add a new row it sends the user id with it. So i want to get the 'gebruikernaam' from the table gebruikers were the id is equal to the one in projecturen.

Comment: I don't what your tables look like so struggling to follow exactly what you're describing. The join: `projecturen`.gebruikersid=`gebruikers`.gebruikersnaam doesn't make sense to me - surely it should be something like `projecturen`.gebruikersid=`gebruikers`.gebruikersid?

Comment: Projecturen has the following rows "id projectid gebruikerid uren datum
" Gebruikers has the following: "id gebruikersnaam naam achternaam" which contains general user information. I want to display the naam from the table Gebruikers but the condition is that the id in table Gebruikers should be equal to GebruikersID in Projecturen. And I only want to display the naam from gebruikers with that equal id.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer - hopefully if I've understood you right it should now provide what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i didn't think clear enough to get the solution I wanted. Right now it works the way I wanted. I'm gonna update my post to post the answer.

Comment: Cool - glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT gebruikersid.projecturen gebruikersnaam.gebruikers 
FROM `projecturen` 
LEFT JOIN `gebruikers` ON gebruikersid.projecturen=gebruikersnaam.gebruikers 
WHERE projectid= '$projecturenid'
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesnt seem to work, my page isn't showing up. $projecturenid got a value. projectid is from projecturen, so it should only selects the ones which are equal to $projecturenid and then display the user who added a value to the database.

Comment: I'm sorry but you query worked, i forgot to close the loop. although i get this: Unknown column 'gebruikerid.projecturen' in 'field list'. gebruikerid exists in the table projecturen. So i'm not sure why its saying this